# Session variable not working when the same php file is called in 2 html files

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm making a site for the doctors to use. Once they login, I'm creating a session variable `$doctorid=$_SESSION['DOCTOR_ID'];`
After this I'm retrieving the data from the database using **load_user.php** and I echo it to the **view.html** file.

This is being used to get the doctor's name on the top right side in the website, i.e, on the navbar.

Now the problem is when I make another HTML file to get the same navbar on the page by calling the same **load_user.php** file, the navbar is not being displayed.

I have included the code of both the files below:

**load_user.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$doctorid=$_SESSION['DOCTOR_ID'];
if($doctorid==-1 || !isset($_SESSION['DOCTOR_ID'])){
    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
    exit(0);
}
$results=execute_MYSQL("SELECT * FROM DOCTORS WHERE  DOCTOR_ID=$doctorid");
echo "<script>console.log('SELECT * FROM DOCTORS WHERE DOCTOR_ID=$doctorid');</script>";


if($results->num_rows==1){
  $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
  $doctor_name=$row['DOCTOR_NAME'];
  $doctor_email=$row['DOCTOR_EMAIL'];
  $doctor_designation=$row['DOCTOR_DESIGNATION'];

echo"   <ul class='nav'>
      <li>
        <img id='doctor_image' src='bci-logo.png'>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href='#'>BLUE CROSS OF INDIA</a>
    </li>
    <li style='float:right'>";

if(file_exists('user_images/'.$doctorid.'.jpg')){
echo "<img id='doctor_image' src='user_images/$doctorid.jpg' alt=\"Image not found\" onError=\"this.src='user_images/default.png'\">";
}
else{
echo "<img id='doctor_image' src='user_images/default.jpg' alt=\"Image  not found\" onError=\"this.src='user_images/default.png'\">
      <!--<form id='upload_image' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input id='fileToUpload' type='file' accept='image/*' name='fileToUpload'/><div id='upload_image' onclick='upload_image()'>Upload DP</div></form>-->";
  }


echo" </li>
    <li id='options' style='float:right'>
    <a href='#' id='docid'> Dr. ".$doctor_name." </a>
    <ul class='subnav'>
            <li><a href='#'>Settings</a></li>";
if($doctorid==0)
{
    echo"<li><a href='#'   onclick='window.location.href=\"view_users.html\"'>View Doctors</a></li>
     <li><a href='#' onclick='window.location.href=\"add_user.html\"'>Add Doctor</a></li>";
      //<div id='edit_user' onclick='window.location.href=\"edit_user.html\"'>Edit Profile</div>
}
    echo "<li><a href='#' onclick='activate_logOut()'>Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li id='search' style='float:right'>
                <form action='' method='get'>
                    <input type='text' name='search_text'  id='search_text' placeholder='Search'/>
                    <input type='button' name='search_button' id='search_button'></a>
                </form>
            </li></ul>";
  }

function execute_MYSQL($sql){
 //DATABASE DETAILS
  }?>
```

**view.html**

```
<html>

<div id="doctor_pane1">

</div>

</html>
```

Comment: We don't need to see all of your code.  Please edit your question and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think this is the logical problem , what value would you give to '$_SESSION['DOCTOR_ID']'  when you call 'load_user.php' first time?

Comment: $_SESSION[] would be empty array if you don't give anything